# Twilio - Putting two callers in the same dynamically-generated conference room creates infinite loop

Tags: php, twilio

I've seen some Twilio experts answer other questions on here before about using Twilio's service so I'm hoping this catches the eye of one of them. :)

Essentially, I need to create a system whereby two callers can connect (a sales agent and a customer) with the capability for a manager to listen in to a live call. From my research into Twilio's API I believe the only way to accomplish this is to have each call be a conference call, and allow the managers to join that call in 'muted' mode, thereby only allowing them to listen to the call between the agent and customer.

I'm developing in PHP and I believe I have 90% of the puzzle solved, however I'm have trouble with one small detail.

I'll lay out the logical flow below so you can see what I'm trying to do:

1) Customer or Sales Agent dials a number.

2) Conference room gets dynamically generated and the person dialing out is placed into that room.

3) I use the REST API to make a call request to the other number, then direct them into the conference room that was already generated with the first person waiting.

I have steps 1 and 2 completed and working fine, step 3 is where the problem occurs. When I use the API to generate the second call to bring the other person into the conference room the request goes through the same application that was used to generate the first call, thereby creating an infinite loop of making new calls and generating new rooms. I have attached my code below to help explain the issue.

```
public function index()
{
   if (isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'])) {
        // The agent is making a call (outgoing)
        $data['callerId']  = $this->users->getPhoneNumber($_REQUEST['Caller']);
        $userIdExplode = explode(':', $_REQUEST['Caller']);
        $data['userId'] = $userIdExplode[1];
        $callTarget = $this->security->xss_clean($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']);
        $data['numberOrClient'] = "<Number>" . $callTarget . "</Number>";
        $data['phoneIsOnline']  = $this->users->isPhoneOnline($data['userId']);

        // Call log information
        $data['ani']  = $data['callerId'];
        $data['dnis'] = $callTarget;

    } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['To'])) { 

        // The agent is receiving a call (incoming)
        $callTarget = $this->security->xss_clean($_REQUEST['To']);
        $data['userId'] = $this->users->getIdByPhoneNumber($callTarget);
        $data['numberOrClient'] = "<Client>" . $data['userId'] . "</Client>";
        $data['phoneIsOnline']  = $this->users->isPhoneOnline($data['userId']);

        // Call log information
        $data['ani']  = $_REQUEST['From'];
        $data['dnis'] = $_REQUEST['To'];
    }

    // Log the new call and receive it's log ID
    $data['callLogId'] = $this->call->logNewCall($data['ani'], $data['dnis'], $data['userId']);

    // Load the TWIML (Twilio XML) to bring the caller into a conference room
    $this->load->view('twilio/connections_twiml', $data);

    // Bring the destination number into the same conference room as the origin number 
    $this->dialToConference($data['ani'], $data['dnis'], $data['callLogId']);
}

public function dialToConference($caller, $callee, $confNum) 
{
    // Twilio capability library (capable of incoming and outgoing calls)
    include APPPATH . 'libraries/twilio/Services/Twilio.php';

    // Twilio account codes required for the client
    $accountSid = $this->config->item('twilio_accountSid');
    $authToken  = $this->config->item('twilio_authToken');

    $client = new Services_Twilio($accountSid, $authToken);
    $call = $client->account->calls->create(
        $caller,
        $callee,
        BASE_URL . 'twilio/twilio_connections/loadConferenceTwiml?conferenceId=' . $confNum
    );
}
```

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  It looks like you are passing the generated conference ID back to Twilio as a querystring parameter of the Voice URL, which is a good way to do that.  But I don't see in your index function where your looking to see if that request parameter is set, and if it is skipping the call to the dialToConference function.  Does that help?

Comment: Hey Devin, ya that helped out quite a bit. I'm not sure why I didn't think about checking to see if that variable was set or not...been staring at the code for too long :)

Comment: @Kody458 does the issue resolved?